# How to set the same width for number in enumerate

Tags: enumerate, width

I have this code, to make a blue ball with white numbers inside, but the numbers have different `width` and I want to make them even, all with the same width, the largest want.

```
\usepackage{wboiboites}

\newcommand*{\itemball}[1]{% bolas 3D
\footnotesize\protect\tikz[baseline=-3pt]%
\protect\node[scale=.7, circle, shade, ball
color=blue]{\color{white}\bf#1};}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\itemball{\arabic*},leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=*]
\setcounter{\enumi}{7}
\item Some text numbered as 8.
\item Some text numbered as 9.
\item Some text numbered as 10.
\item Some text numbered as 11.
\item Some text numbered as 12.
\item Some text numbered as 13.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

How I can do it?

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> c@\enumi 
                    
l.12 \setcounter{\enumi}{7}

Comment: Please fix your exampele so it may be run, I tried replacing `wboiboits` by `tikz,emuitem` but got the above error, so gave up guessing.

Comment: You could add a minimum width to the node...,

Comment: I use the `\setcounter{enumi}{7}` to start the numeration at 8 for an example and to avoid to write 13 items in `enumerate` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,enumitem}

\newcommand*{\itemball}[1]{% bolas 3D
\footnotesize\protect\tikz[baseline=-3pt]%
\protect\node[text width=2em,align=center,scale=.7, circle, shade, ball
color=blue]{\color{white}\bf#1};}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[start=7,label=\itemball{\arabic*},leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=*]
\item Some text numbered as 8.
\item Some text numbered as 9.
\item Some text numbered as 10.
\item Some text numbered as 11.
\item Some text numbered as 12.
\item Some text numbered as 13.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So, I just neened to add `text width=2em,align=center` to that node code line. That was great and changed the measure from `2em` to `1em` to make the numbers to fit a little better.